# How to find shortest path for raw data

Tags: python, social-networking, networkx

I have a data file, that has categorical data as columns. like

```
node_id,second_major,gender,major_index,year,dorm,high_school,student_fac
0,0,2,257,2007,111,2849,1
1,0,2,271,2005,0,51195,2
2,0,2,269,2007,0,21462,1
3,269,1,245,2008,111,2597,1
..........................
```

This data are in columns. I convert it as edgelist and nodelist.
The edgelist like:

```
0   4191
0   949
1   3002
1   4028
1   957
2   2494
2   959
2   3011
3   4243
4   965
5   1478
........
........
```

What exactly have to be done to find the shortest path between the nodes. There is no weights to edges. How shall I implement a code for this in python?

Comment: removed the `matplotlib` tag as I don't see how this is related to plotting.  If you disagree feel free to put it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic **Breadth First Search** problem, where you have an undirected, unweighted graph and you want to find the shortest path between 2 vertices.

Some helpful links on Breadth First Search:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search
- http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~stevenha/visualization/dfsbfs.html (JavaScript visualization of breadth-first search algorithm)

Some edge cases that you have to take note of:

- No path between the source and destination vertices
- Source and destination are the same vertex

I'll suppose that your edge list is a dictionary of lists or a list of lists, eg.

```
[[4191, 949], [3002, 4028, 957], [2494, 959, 3011], [4243, 965], [1478], ...]
```

Or

```
{ 0: [4191, 949],
  1: [3002, 4028, 957],
  2: [2494, 959, 3011],
  3: [4243, 965],
  4: [1478], ...}
```

I've written some code to show how the breadth first search works:

```
import sys
import sys
import Queue

def get_shortest_path(par, src, dest):
    '''
    Returns the shortest path as a list of integers
    par - parent information
    src - source vertex
    dest - destination vertex
    '''
    if dest == src:
        return [src]
    else:
        ret = get_shortest_path(par, src, par[dest])
        ret.append(dest)
        return ret

def bfs(edgeList, src, dest):
    '''
    Breadth first search routine. Returns (distance, shortestPath) pair from src to dest. Returns (-1, []) if there is no path from src to dest
    edgeList - adjacency list of graph. Either list of lists or dict of lists
    src - source vertex
    dest - destination vertex
    '''
    vis = set() # stores the vertices that have been visited
    par = {} # stores parent information. vertex -> parent vertex in BFS tree
    distDict = {} # stores distance of visited vertices from the source. This is the number of edges between the source vertex and the given vertex
    q = Queue.Queue()
    q.put((src, 0)) # enqueue (source, distance) pair
    par[src] = -1 # source has no parent
    vis.add(src) # minor technicality, will explain later
    while not q.empty():
        (v,dist) = q.get() # grab vertex in queue
        distDict[v] = dist # update the distance
        if v == dest:
            break # reached destination, done
        nextDist = dist+1
        for nextV in edgeList[v]:
            # visit vertices adjacent to the current vertex
            if nextV not in vis:
                # not yet visited
                par[nextV] = v # update parent of nextV to v
                q.put((nextV, nextDist)) # add into queeu
                vis.add(nextV) # mark as visited
    # obtained shortest path now
    if dest in distDict:
        return (distDict[dest], get_shortest_path(par, src, dest))
    else:
        return (-1, []) # no shortest path

# example run, feel free to remove this
if __name__ == '__main__':
    edgeList = {
        0: [6,],
        1: [2, 7],
        2: [1, 3, 6],
        3: [2, 4, 5],
        4: [3, 8],
        5: [3, 7],
        6: [0, 2],
        7: [1, 5],
        8: [4],
    }
    while True:
        src = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        dest = int(sys.stdin.readline())
        (dist, shortest_path) = bfs(edgeList, src, dest)
        print 'dist =', dist
        print 'shortest_path =', shortest_path
```

Comment: sure, no problem. it was good practice for me to use Python to write bfs as well =)